# converting mV to g

Tags: accelerometer, conversion, vibration

I have recently run a vibration test at work using a PCB piezotronics model 482C sensor signal conditioner. How do you convert the the MAX reading (in mV) into the equivalent acceleration (in g). The max reading was 205mV.

Answer (score 1):

In general you'd refer to the datasheet of the accelerometer you used, look at the sensitivity figures (or the individual sensor calibration figures if the maker supplied them) and work back through the gain settings in the signal conditioner. The signal conditioner can be set with several orders of magnitude different gain, and the accelerometer has unknown sensitivity. You need both (they are multiplied) to relate output mV to input g.

Comment: OK I'm deleting my comments.  The 482C is an entire instrument, not just a single sensor.  (my bad.)

Answer (score 0):

*Make measurements with the accelerometer in the gravity axis. The axis that points from the center of the earth to infinity. Make sure the accelerometer is steady and write that number down. This is the voltage when you have 1 G of acceleration. For example `V(1g)=600`

*Do the same with the X axis. Make sure the sensor is as parallel to the ground as possible. That means keep it completely flat. That axis reads `0 G`. Write down the voltage you get from the accelerometer because that is the `0 G` voltage. For example `V(0g)=500`

That means that between `1 G` we have a difference of 600-500 = 100 discrete voltage levels for this example. Let's call this number scale. `Scale = 100`

So to convert any voltage to G's, remove the 0g voltage (500 for our example) and subtract with the scale.

`G(X) = (x_reading - zero_G_reading)/scale;`

for this example:
`Gx=(x-500)/100`

Comment: AFAIUI, If they're PCB piezo accelerometers they don't have a DC response so you can't calibrate with a static field as you could with a MEMS or QFLEX accelerometer.

Comment: Didnt know that. Thanks. Also i dont understand half of what you just said, but you certainly widened my perspective. I will look it up

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, so what is their time constant?  Maybe put it in a spring or torsional oscillator and calculate the acceleration from first principles.  (Newtons laws etc.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I think they can do down to ~1Hz-ish, but 10Hz might be more reliable.